# Not show map and markers on map

Tags: android, google-maps

Android Studio 3.0, Gradle 4.4, Java 1.8, Android 6.0
I try to show google map with markers on it.
So.
In manifest file:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Here my code in Fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Debug.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: GRANTED ---> moveMyLocation()");
                        myLastLocation = getMyLastLocation();
                        MyApplication.setMyLocation(myLastLocation);
                        moveMyLastLocation();
                        updateMarkers();
                    } else {
                        Debug.w(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: NOT_GRANTED");
                    }
                } else {
                    Debug.w(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: NOT GRANEED");
                }
            }
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

  private void updateMarkers() {
        for (Marker marker : markersList) {
            marker.remove();
        }
        RealmResults<Merchant> merchantsRealmResults = MerchantService.getMerchants(realm, filter, null);
        for (Merchant merchant : merchantsRealmResults) {
            RealmList<PointOfSale> pointOfSaleRealmList = merchant.getPointsOfSale();
            for (PointOfSale pointOfSale : pointOfSaleRealmList) {
                Coordinates coordinates = pointOfSale.getCoordinates();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(coordinates.getLatitude(), coordinates.getLongitude());
                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_info_marker));
                marker.setTag(pointOfSale);
                markersList.add(marker);
            }
        }
        Debug.d(TAG, "updateMarkers: markersList.size = " + markersList.size());
    }
```

as result (logcat):

```
 onMapReady: 
 onMapReady: ---> permission is already granted
 onConnected: 
 onConnected: ---> permission is already granted ---> updateMarkers() and moveMyLocation()
 updateMarkers: filter = 
 BUNDLE(0):

 getMerchants: sortByFieldName = null, filter = 
 BUNDLE(0):

 updateMarkers: current pointOfSale = 
 id = 238, coordinates = Coordinates{latitude = 35.3237104, longitude = 33.3149413}}
 updateMarkers: current pointOfSale = 
 id = 227, coordinates = Coordinates{latitude = 35.126413, longitude = 33.429859}}
updateMarkers: markersList.size = 2
```

as you can see I success add all marksers to markersList, but map is empty.

On first start it ask my about permission. I select "**Allow**"
[image]

But map is not show. Also not show markers on map.

[image]

also in logcat:

```
E/Google Maps Android API(21307): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API(21307): In the Google Developer Console 

(https://console.developers.google.com)
E/Google Maps Android API(21307): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
E/Google Maps Android API(21307): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
E/Google Maps Android API(21307):   API Key: AIzaSyxxxx1BRHy1GhlvJvj7dcAmAc-Is
E/Google Maps Android API(21307):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): xxxxxB:1A:0D:B9;com.my.projectandroid.customer.debug
```

Why not show map and markers on it?

Comment: Did you use the right google_maps_key?

Comment: Before 2 months, the markers success show. But today not show anymore.

Comment: How I can check is I use correct google_maps_key ?

Comment: By the image above it looks like a problem with the google maps key or any sort of permission missing on manifest.

Comment: To get the maps key you can check it out on google cloud platform console by this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

Comment: I update my post. Add logcat logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logcat says that you need set up the google maps api and get a valid api key and that's the reason why the map fragment displays this blank screen. To get the google maps api key you need to go to [Google Api](https://console.developers.google.com/) and add your project to google maps android api.

The logcat provides the links to solve your problem [first link - step 4](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) and [second link](https://console.developers.google.com/)